# How can I view a website running in localhost on machine in chrome browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, networking, mobile

I am working on a rails web app, currently focusing on the mobile design and would like to view html screens I have developed in the mobile chrome browser on my Galaxy Nexus (running Jelly Bean).

On my MacBook Pro I am able, obviously, to run a local server and view the site on my machine via LocalHost:3000 url. Would it be possible to complete some network configuration on my phone/macbook pro to view the Local Host site on my phone when its running on my machine? Could Chrome Dev Tools be leveraged in anyway?

e.g.

https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging

+5 cool points for whoever answers this question. :)

Comment: Why can't you just `http://yourMachinesHostNameOrIP/` (or `http://yourMachinesHostNameOrIP:3000/` if that's the port you're running on). Have you checked your firewall isn't blocking that port?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On your mac go open your network preferences (click the wifi signal at the top). Find the ip address of the network you are currently connected to. In the browser of your phone, type in that ip address and append :3000 to the end of it

Comment: What happens when you still get "This webpage is not available"?

Comment: When I try to do this, I get following error: "This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". Any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 24):

For anyone using Rails 4.2, trying to access via ip address will probably fail due to [a change in Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#default-host-for-rails-server).

Start the server using `rails server -b 0.0.0.0` would allow you to access your localhost from your phone like before.

Comment: I wish I could give this answer +1000. Spent way too long trying everything before this.