# Can't sign in to local host through android phone ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost

I tried to follow these directions to view my development version of my site on my phone. -> [How can I view a website running in localhost on machine in chrome browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849535/how-can-i-view-a-website-running-in-localhost-on-machine-in-chrome-browser) It works ok... until I after I sign in. I direct my browser to 192.168.1.48:3000 and it pulls up the sign in page. After logging in, the url changes to test-account.:3000/home and the browser reads "This webpage is not available". On my local host the url becomes 'http://test-account.pete.dev:3000/home' I have tried several variations of the URL, including 'test-account.pete.dev/192.168.1.48:3000' Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two scenarios in which something like this could happen: Either you are having an absolute url somewhere (that is being set dynamically, as it is different on the phone and on the pc) or in some of your config files you have set a base url. I mean, it is already strange that it does not go to localhost:3000/home on the computer.